# How to add a keyframe to a frame frame different than the current one?

Tags: transforms, keyframes

Is it possible to add a keyframe to a frame different then the current one ?

In other softwares I can modify my transforms then open a menu to choose to what frame set the keyframe for those transformations.

How can I do this in blender ? Currently I can only:

1. Make some transfomations
2. Keyframe current frame
3. Move to a new frame
4. Repeat 1

I want:

1. Stay on frame 0
2. Make transformations
3. Add key to frame 10
4. Make transformations
5. Add key to frame 20
6. ...
7. ...
8. Make transformations
9. Add key to frame XX

All while remaining at frame 0.

Comment: You could duplicate current frame in Graph Editor and "draw" animation from there, moving keyframes where desired.. Although that's not very controllable in terms of visualization.

Comment: Try using the NLA editor to move the keyframes where you want them after keying them at frame 0 from the timeline. . Same basic thing as what MrZak suggests.